# Many to many relation. Display data in template

Tags: django, django-models

I learn Django ORM.

```
class Toy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    desc = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class Box(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    proprietor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='User_Box')
    toys = models.ManyToManyField(Toy, blank=True)
```

I try something like this in views:

```
def show_box(request):
    user = request.user
    box = Box.objects.filter(proprietor = user)

    return render_to_response('box.html', {'box': box})
```

in template:

```
{% for b in box %}
    Toy: {% for toys in b.toys.all %}{{ toys }}<br/>{% endfor %} 
    Price:
{% endfor %}
```

How to display the price of toys in template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just with the normal dot notation. `toys` is an instance of the Toy model so you can access the attributes on it:

```
{% for box in boxes %}
    {% for toy in box.toys.all %}
        Toy: {{ toy.name }}<br/>
        Price: {{ toy.price }}<br/>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that I've changed your variable names, which were confusing: the `box` variable that you passed to the template should really be `boxes`, as it's a set of all the boxes owned by that proprietor, while `toys` inside the template should be `toy`, as it's one specific toy from a box, not a set.